# Select with Sub Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have two selects in my procedure, but I want to select just the rows that the IDENTIFICACAO_A from the first Select are in common with the IDENTIFICACAO_B from the second Select.

Query:

```
SELECT
(CONVERT(VARCHAR,fic.reg_codigo_lotado_atual) + '.' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,fic.cla_codigo) + '.' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,fic.reg_codigo_lotado_origem) + '.' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,fic.fic_numero_livro) + '/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,fic.fic_versao)) AS IDENTIFICACAO_A,
cla.cla_nome,
fic.fic_ca,
fic.fic_fa,
fic.reg_codigo_lotado_atual,
fic.cla_codigo,
fic.reg_codigo_lotado_origem,
fic.fic_numero_livro,
fic.fic_versao,
fic.fic_ato_oficial,
fic_localizacao_numero,
fic_localizacao_data_em,
qua.qua_nome,
fic.fic_localizacao_do,
adm.adm_codigo_ua,
adm.adm_codigo_uv,
adm.adm_digito,
adm.adm_decodificada,
adm.adm_sigla,
form.for_nome,
fic.fic_ocupacao_data,
fic.fic_ocupacao_do,
fic.fic_ocupacao_data_cessacao,
fic.fic_ocupacao_do_cessacao,
ser.ser_nome,
ser.ser_rg,
ser.ser_cpf,
fic.fic_ocupacao_observacao,
esp.esp_descricao,
fic.fic_alteracao_vigencia,
fic.fic_alteracao_decreto,
fic.fic_alteracao_data,
fic.fic_alteracao_qua_codigo,
fic.fic_alteracao_do,
fic.fic_situacao_vc,
fic.fic_situacao_pp,
fic.fic_situacao_ocupado,
fic.fic_nova_identificacao,
fic.fic_observacoes_gerais
FROM
SICAF.dbo.tab_fichas AS fic
 INNER JOIN
SICAF.dbo.tab_classes AS cla ON cla.cla_codigo = fic.cla_codigo
 LEFT JOIN
SICAF.dbo.tab_sub_quadros AS qua ON qua.qua_codigo = fic.qua_codigo
 LEFT JOIN
SICAF.dbo.tab_unidade_adm AS adm ON adm.adm_codigo = fic.adm_codigo
 LEFT JOIN
SICAF.dbo.tab_formas AS form ON form.for_codigo = fic.for_codigo
 LEFT JOIN
SICAF.dbo.tab_servidores AS ser ON ser.ser_codigo = fic.ser_codigo
 LEFT JOIN
SICAF.dbo.tab_especies AS esp ON esp.esp_codigo = fic.esp_codigo


SELECT
(CONVERT(VARCHAR,fic.reg_codigo_lotado_atual) + '.' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,fic.cla_codigo) + '.' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,fic.reg_codigo_lotado_origem) + '.' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,fic.fic_numero_livro) + '/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,fic.fic_versao)) AS IDENTIFICACAO_B,
cla.cla_nome,
fic.fic_ca,
fic.fic_fa,
fic.reg_codigo_lotado_atual,
fic.cla_codigo,
fic.reg_codigo_lotado_origem,
fic.fic_numero_livro,
fic.fic_versao,
fic.fic_ato_oficial,
fic_localizacao_numero,
fic_localizacao_data_em,
qua.qua_nome,
fic.fic_localizacao_do,
adm.adm_codigo_ua,
adm.adm_codigo_uv,
adm.adm_digito,
adm.adm_decodificada,
adm.adm_sigla,
form.for_nome,
fic.fic_ocupacao_data,
fic.fic_ocupacao_do,
fic.fic_ocupacao_data_cessacao,
fic.fic_ocupacao_do_cessacao,
ser.ser_nome,
ser.ser_rg,
ser.ser_cpf,
fic.fic_ocupacao_observacao,
esp.esp_descricao,
fic.fic_alteracao_vigencia,
fic.fic_alteracao_decreto,
fic.fic_alteracao_data,
fic.fic_alteracao_qua_codigo,
fic.fic_alteracao_do,
fic.fic_situacao_vc,
fic.fic_situacao_pp,
fic.fic_situacao_ocupado,
fic.fic_nova_identificacao,
fic.fic_observacoes_gerais
FROM
SICAF2.dbo.tab_fichas AS fic
 INNER JOIN
SICAF2.dbo.tab_classes AS cla ON cla.cla_codigo = fic.cla_codigo
 LEFT JOIN
SICAF2.dbo.tab_sub_quadros AS qua ON qua.qua_codigo = fic.qua_codigo
 LEFT JOIN
SICAF2.dbo.tab_unidade_adm AS adm ON adm.adm_codigo = fic.adm_codigo
 LEFT JOIN
SICAF2.dbo.tab_formas AS form ON form.for_codigo = fic.for_codigo
 LEFT JOIN
SICAF2.dbo.tab_servidores AS ser ON ser.ser_codigo = fic.ser_codigo
 LEFT JOIN
SICAF2.dbo.tab_especies AS esp ON esp.esp_codigo = fic.esp_codigo
```

What can I do to return both Selects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use inner join between both queries:

```
Select * From 
(
SELECT
(CONVERT(VARCHAR,fic.reg_codigo_lotado_atual) + '.' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,fic.cla_codigo) + '.' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,fic.reg_codigo_lotado_origem) + '.' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,fic.fic_numero_livro) + '/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,fic.fic_versao)) AS IDENTIFICACAO_A,
cla.cla_nome,
fic.fic_ca,
fic.fic_fa,
fic.reg_codigo_lotado_atual,
fic.cla_codigo,
fic.reg_codigo_lotado_origem,
fic.fic_numero_livro,
fic.fic_versao,
fic.fic_ato_oficial,
fic_localizacao_numero,
fic_localizacao_data_em,
qua.qua_nome,
fic.fic_localizacao_do,
adm.adm_codigo_ua,
adm.adm_codigo_uv,
adm.adm_digito,
adm.adm_decodificada,
adm.adm_sigla,
form.for_nome,
fic.fic_ocupacao_data,
fic.fic_ocupacao_do,
fic.fic_ocupacao_data_cessacao,
fic.fic_ocupacao_do_cessacao,
ser.ser_nome,
ser.ser_rg,
ser.ser_cpf,
fic.fic_ocupacao_observacao,
esp.esp_descricao,
fic.fic_alteracao_vigencia,
fic.fic_alteracao_decreto,
fic.fic_alteracao_data,
fic.fic_alteracao_qua_codigo,
fic.fic_alteracao_do,
fic.fic_situacao_vc,
fic.fic_situacao_pp,
fic.fic_situacao_ocupado,
fic.fic_nova_identificacao,
fic.fic_observacoes_gerais
FROM
SICAF.dbo.tab_fichas AS fic
 INNER JOIN
SICAF.dbo.tab_classes AS cla ON cla.cla_codigo = fic.cla_codigo
 LEFT JOIN
SICAF.dbo.tab_sub_quadros AS qua ON qua.qua_codigo = fic.qua_codigo
 LEFT JOIN
SICAF.dbo.tab_unidade_adm AS adm ON adm.adm_codigo = fic.adm_codigo
 LEFT JOIN
SICAF.dbo.tab_formas AS form ON form.for_codigo = fic.for_codigo
 LEFT JOIN
SICAF.dbo.tab_servidores AS ser ON ser.ser_codigo = fic.ser_codigo
 LEFT JOIN
SICAF.dbo.tab_especies AS esp ON esp.esp_codigo = fic.esp_codigo
)tbl1

Inner Join 
(
SELECT
(CONVERT(VARCHAR,fic.reg_codigo_lotado_atual) + '.' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,fic.cla_codigo) + '.' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,fic.reg_codigo_lotado_origem) + '.' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,fic.fic_numero_livro) + '/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,fic.fic_versao)) AS IDENTIFICACAO_B,
cla.cla_nome,
fic.fic_ca,
fic.fic_fa,
fic.reg_codigo_lotado_atual,
fic.cla_codigo,
fic.reg_codigo_lotado_origem,
fic.fic_numero_livro,
fic.fic_versao,
fic.fic_ato_oficial,
fic_localizacao_numero,
fic_localizacao_data_em,
qua.qua_nome,
fic.fic_localizacao_do,
adm.adm_codigo_ua,
adm.adm_codigo_uv,
adm.adm_digito,
adm.adm_decodificada,
adm.adm_sigla,
form.for_nome,
fic.fic_ocupacao_data,
fic.fic_ocupacao_do,
fic.fic_ocupacao_data_cessacao,
fic.fic_ocupacao_do_cessacao,
ser.ser_nome,
ser.ser_rg,
ser.ser_cpf,
fic.fic_ocupacao_observacao,
esp.esp_descricao,
fic.fic_alteracao_vigencia,
fic.fic_alteracao_decreto,
fic.fic_alteracao_data,
fic.fic_alteracao_qua_codigo,
fic.fic_alteracao_do,
fic.fic_situacao_vc,
fic.fic_situacao_pp,
fic.fic_situacao_ocupado,
fic.fic_nova_identificacao,
fic.fic_observacoes_gerais
FROM
SICAF2.dbo.tab_fichas AS fic
 INNER JOIN
SICAF2.dbo.tab_classes AS cla ON cla.cla_codigo = fic.cla_codigo
 LEFT JOIN
SICAF2.dbo.tab_sub_quadros AS qua ON qua.qua_codigo = fic.qua_codigo
 LEFT JOIN
SICAF2.dbo.tab_unidade_adm AS adm ON adm.adm_codigo = fic.adm_codigo
 LEFT JOIN
SICAF2.dbo.tab_formas AS form ON form.for_codigo = fic.for_codigo
 LEFT JOIN
SICAF2.dbo.tab_servidores AS ser ON ser.ser_codigo = fic.ser_codigo
 LEFT JOIN
SICAF2.dbo.tab_especies AS esp ON esp.esp_codigo = fic.esp_codigo
)tbl2
On tbl1.IDENTIFICACAO_A=tbl2.IDENTIFICACAO_B
```

Comment: I need to return two Selects, because I want to show the difference between the values of the two collunms.

Comment: You can take difference in your outer select: (tbl1.ColumnName -tbl2.ColumnName) as AnotherColumnName

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
select your_fields from table1

intersect

select your_fields from table2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use union.

Rename the key column to be the same on both queries, and i would also recommend to save both queries as a temp tables.

So let's say you have your first query stored in temp table `q1` and second query in `q2` and the key column on both is `id`.

```
select from q1 where q1.id in (select id from q2)
union
select from q2 where q2.id in (select id from q1)
```

Hope I was clear.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `IN` here. T1 is group of joined tables from first query and T2 is group of joined tables from second query. Syntax is as below.

```
Select col1,col2,...
From T1
Where IDENTIFICACAO_A in (
   Select IDENTIFICACAO_B
   From T2
)
```

You can replace `IDENTIFICACAO_A` and `IDENTIFICACAO_B` column names with their concatenated results

If `T1` and `T`2 (described above) are same then;

```
SELECT X AS IDENTIFICACAO_A,
   cla.cla_nome,
   fic.fic_ca,...
FROM T1
WHERE X = Y
```

You can replace `X` and `Y` with their string concatenating functions.